# How to remove a volume that is linked to a disconnected network drive

Tags: windows-10, mount, nfs, network-drive, drive-letter

I have a disconnected network drive that is linked to a volume (N:). It used to be linked to an NFS share on `127.0.0.1\data` (using WinNFSd), but I didn't need it anymore.

[image: Disconnected network drive]

I am trying to remove it, because I want to use the drive letter for another drive, but it doesn't seem to want to be deleted. I tried the following:

- right clicking it freezes my Explorer and I have to kill explorer through task manager and restart it
- right click `This PC` -> `Disconnect network drive...` and select the volume gave the following error: [image: Unable to disconnect network drive through explorer]
- trying to find it in the disk manager didn't help either. It's not listed: [image: Not showing up in disk manager]
- using powershell to run diskpart to show the volumes also doesn't show N:
  [image: Not showing up in diskpart]
- running `net use` doesn't show anything either:

  [image]
- Restarting the NFS daemon makes it so that (right)clicking the mount doesn't crash explorer and allows me to successfully connect to the files that the NFS was mounted to, but clicking disconnect on that volume mount gives the following error: [image: Unable to disconnect from volume mount]

**Can anyone help me get rid of this volume mount?**

Comment: If you haven't already removed WinNFSd, try re-creating the NFS share on 127.0.0.1\data with it, then disconnect drive N:

Comment: Could you 1) check `subst`, 2) check `mountvol`, 3) check `reg query HKCU\Network /s`, and 4) use WinObj or WinObjEx to check where the \DosDevices\N link points?

Comment: @leeharvey1 that's what I tried already, as explained in my last bullet point. It unfortunately didn't do the trick, but luckily I did find a solution in the end. See my answer.

Comment: @user1686 I indeed also stumbled upon `mountvol` after asking the question and that seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mountvol N: /D` seems to have worked.

I don't remember if I reconnected to the NFS share before trying this though, so if anyone experiences a similar issue and the command doesn't work, it wouldn't hurt trying to reconnect the share before trying the command again.