# Volume linked to a disconnected network drive can be remvoed but reappears on machine reboot

Tags: windows-10, mount, network-drive, drive-letter, mapped-drive

I have the same issue as described in in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1708367/how-to-remove-a-volume-that-is-linked-to-a-disconnected-network-drive), namely that my machine has a disconnected network drive in my mapped drives. Running `mountvol [DRIVE-LETTER]: /D` successfully removes the disconnected mapped drive, but upon reboot it reappears.

Comment: Do again `mountvol /D`, then use `regedit` to check if the mapping still exists in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Shares` and its subkey `Security`. If it exists, delete it and test by reboot.

Comment: Try NET USE Z: /Delete for the drives you do not want to reappear

Comment: Also make sure the user that deletes the drive mapping is the user who set it up in the first instance

Comment: @John Unfortunately the original user in question's account was deleted before the machine was given to me.

Comment: @harrymc The mapping wasn't present at that location in the registry after mountvol /D. Upon restart the drive still reappears. I went back and checked the same registry location after the reappearance of the disconnected drive and there was still nothing there either.

Comment: @John Also, the connection does not exist according to net use.

Comment: You said the machine was given to you from another user, so I assume you are in a company. Have you asked IT Support?

Comment: Try searching your registry for the share name.  A good tool is [RegScanner](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/regscanner.html).